# Why is my C program displaying a different int than what it should be

Tags: c, runtime-error

This is an excerpt from my code. It reads a file and puts the first line into a `char` and then puts part of that first line into an int. The first line of the file is "10 20". The file does get closed later on. The output when I print temp is 10 20, but when I print rct it is 49 and cct is 32. I am completely new to c and don't really know why this is wrong.

```
FILE *matrix;
char *temporary = argv[5];
matrix = fopen(temporary,"r");
if (matrix == NULL)
{
    perror(argv[5]);
    exit(1);
}
int rct, cct;
char temp[10];
fgets (temp, 10, matrix);
rct = temp[0];
cct = temp[2];
```

Comment: Please post an MCVE, not some code one cannot diagnose the error with.

Comment: `an excerpt` from my answer : you can solve this by . . . . . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to convert a string to an integer, which you can't do by assignment. What you're actually doing is printing the character code for the first and third characters in the string (49 is ASCII for `'1'`, 32 ASCII for `' '`). Instead, you should use `fscanf` to do the parsing for you.

Answer (score 2):

You need `sscanf` to extract integers from a string. So use:

```
sscanf(temp,"%d %d",&rct,&cct);
```

It is better to check if `sscanf` was successful. So do the following to check the return value of `sscanf` as @chux suggested:

```
if(sscanf(temp,"%d %d",&rct,&cct)==2)
//sscanf is successfull
else
//sscanf failed
```

Currently,you assign a character to `rct` and `cct` and they get the ASCII values of the respective characters. Remember `'0' != 0` because `'0'` has the value 48 in the ASCII table. See more values of the [ASCII table here](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif)